# Tool for plain text comparison by word

Tags: comparison, diff

I need simple tool or library for text comparison. I could use diff by it isn't appropriate because it compare text by lines. Is there tool which could compare plain text by word? At example I have 2 file with long line.

```
File1
aaa bbb .... cccc

File2
aaa eee .... cccc
```

When I use diff it show that there 1 different line.

```
Diff
aaa eee .... cccc
---    
aaa bbb .... cccc
```

I need something like that:

```
Diff
aaa -[bbb] +[eee] ... cccc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called `wdiff` by the GNU project (called after *word diff*). This is a front-end to `diff` which cuts lines on blanks and then compute the word oriented diff from the internal word-lines oriented output.

It should provide results similar to what you need.